# Use wlr-randr from a second user

Tags: raspberry-pi, wayland, debian-based

I'm trying to automate turning my display on and off from the console as a second user (homebridge) on my system. I've been using `wlr-randr` (more specifically `wlr-randr --output HDMI-A-1 --on/off`) to toggle the display, which works fine from the main user (pi). However, when I run this command from a second user (homebridge), i get the following error messages:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
failed to connect to display
```

It seems the second user isn't created with the correct environment variables set, and there is no `~/.Xauthority` file generated. I've also tried using `xrandr` (which outputs correct information for tha main user, but which I haven't been able to use to actually change output configuration), but get a similar error message:

```
Can't open display
```

Is this an issue with permissions? How should I go about solving this?